# Django - 'for' statements should have at least four words: for choice question_set.all

Tags: python, django, for-loop, syntax

everything's cool? It's my first question, english is not my native language so please take it easy on me hahahaha

Ok, so here is the problem, I believe it's a ident... idk how to say it in english but anyway, structural problem.

What's happening: I'm learning following the tutorial and in my localhost website almost everything is running clean but when I decide to "vote" on a "Question", it leads to a error page.

Here's the traceback (the final line):

```
 django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should have at least four words: for choice question_set.all
```

and where the error (I believe) is placed, my "/results.html" file:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
  {% for choice question_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ 
choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

My models.py code (as asked <3):

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone



class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField ('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
was_published_recently.boolean = True
was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

Thanks for everything! hope it's understandable. (:

Comment: Funny. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

You've just forgotten the statement **in**

```
{% for choice in question_set.all %}
```

Comment: hey! thanks for this mate! it resolved some of my problems as I commented above but unlucky I guess it's still not working as it should... 

But thanks a lot! (:

Comment: I guess it was supposed to show me how many votes each "choice" has but instead it only show me "vote again?" option, and, if I didn't choose any of the choices and just press "vote" it should say "no option selected. try again." or something like that but instead it leads to an error page. But I'm not fully sure, at least it was like this on the tutorial I was following, I'm too newbie yet.

Comment: @Lemayzeur under this comment solved part of the problem too, now I know how many votes each choice has, but still going to an error page when not selecting a choice and clicking on vote.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should have something like a ForeignKey to `Question` model to your `Vote` model? If it so, you maybe should do something like this:

```
{% for choice in question.vote_set.all %}
{% empty %}
{% endfor %}
```

If think that we need more information about your models in order to help you. Please add your models code, at least the Question models.

Comment: I've done what Eduardo Calil said and it's workin, i guess not like it should, I mean, it should display the votes and if don't click the button it should say "you didn't choose a choice" or something like this instead of thrown a error page but....... now I can vote and it displays "vote again" so we did one step at least.

I will add my models.py code then (:

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for loop` has to be something like that, accessing via `reverse_name`

> `question.modelname_set.all`

for instance based on your case:

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- 
        {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hey, thank you! it corrected part of my problem, now it shows how many votes each choices has but when I don't select the button it don't say "no choice selected. try again" stuff it stills leads to an error page :/

but thanks for the part solved! (:

Comment: so what do you want to do now?

Comment: To be honest I'm starting a new project to practice what I've learned so although of this error I guess it's all on the way... I mean, to be "perfect" I would like to at least understand why it isn't showd "wrong option. vote again." when voting without an option selected instead of just trown an error page.

Comment: But I don't see any checkboxes in your codes, maybe some parts is missing